# reraising when a player is allin

Tags: rules, tournament

I was in a no limit tournament. The big blind is 1000. I have 4500 left on the button. I have QQ, under the gun raises to 3000, there is one caller, before it folds to me. I just call, knowing I have no fold equity and knowing the bb will call the extra 2000 and I would like to see if an ace or king will come on flop.

My question is, if I go all in for 4500 do I shut down potential re-raising from the players still live in the hand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No-Limit Holdem Partial Raise Clarification](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/no-limit-holdem-partial-raise-clarification)

Comment: Hi Shawn, I am going to urge you to expand your question with an edit, it has the bones of a really good tournament strategy question, about the pros and cons of raising at this point, but all you are asking is a technical rules question about if other players can still raise, which as Herb correctly suggests is a duplicate question with an answer. I suggest add more info about stack sizes etc. and asking about the pros and cons of your situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the min-raise and min-reraise in Holdem No Limit?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/what-is-the-min-raise-and-min-reraise-in-holdem-no-limit)

Comment: Since it is not a min raise then it would not open up action to players  in pot.  Action is still open to blinds.   QQ with 4.5 bb - that is push.   What do you care if they re-raise after you are all in?

Answer (score 4):

To give you a better answer we would really need to know everyones stack sizes, if it's a very short stacked table, a shove might give you some fold-equity, but if the table all have bigger stacks, something like 15+ bbs, then it's not worth even worrying about. But if you have no fold-equity why do you call? I don't think you're understanding what the concept of fold-equity is for, or rather how to apply it.

To put it bluntly, you have 4.5 big blinds, and you have QQ, put your chips in the middle. Calling here is a big mistake. Even if they all call, you have a top premium hand, what are you waiting for with 4.5 bigs? This is pretty much as good as it'll get for your tournament life.

When action gets to you there is 7.5 bb in the pot, you're likely going to be called by shoving, but perhaps the players at the table are bad and only hear the all-in and aren't paying attention to the chips so you get folds. Even still shove pre-flop, big mistake calling, you don't have a stack to call.

In this situation don't worry about fold-equity, you're already crippled and you're goal should be to get it in with a good hand and hope to double or triple up. Would you rather stick 4.5 bbs in with a top hand for the chance to minimum win 7.5 bbs or would you rather call, fold and then stick your last 1.5bb with any random hand for a chance to only win 1.5bb minimum?