# Pot Limit Omaha 8 or better rules

Tags: rules, raise, omaha-hi-lo, pot-limit

I have a question regard PLO/8.

Post flop, player 1 checks, player 2 bets $150.00, player 3 goes all-in for $165.00.

Does player 1 have option to raise player 2, or can he just call player 3's all-in bet?

Comment: related, potential dupe for NLHE, https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/4139/3816

Answer (score 1):

Once any person checks or bets he can't raise anymore unless someone else bets or raises an amount that is more than a min-bet or min-raise.

A min-bet is betting a big blind. A min-raise is essentially calling a bet twice, if that makes sense. In this situation a min-raise would be $300. P1 therefore can still raise, but P2 cannot.

Comment: P1 checked with intention of check raising aggressive P2. It doesn't make sense to me why P1 couldn't make a pot size bet to protect his top set only to lose to gut card making P2 a straight. P2 never would have called a $600.00 plus sized raise.

Comment: Oh you are absolutely right. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Player 1 can raise call or fold when the action gets to him.

Player 2 can only call the 15 dollar raise, this small raise does not reopen the action for player two. When the raise is large enough to reopen the action varies from house to house. Most commonly it needs to be a full raise or more, some places it needs to be a half raise or more. In limit games it was traditionally half the raise would reopen the action. In Pot-limit and no-limit games it should be a full raise to reopen the action. Players are often confused as are dealers and floor people, so your mileage may vary.

Whenever a player goes all in for something less then a full raise (in accordance with house definition of what a full raise is) it is treated as far as subsequent action is concerned like the player simply called. Therefore a checker can still raise, and a bettor cannot. The bettor does need to call the all in however or fold.